# One input topic multiple output topic for Spring cloud stream Kafka Binder

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring cloud stream Kafka Binder. I have following kafka binder function.

```
public Function<T1,T2> f() {
  return d ->{}
}
```

In yml i have :

```
spring:
  cloud:
   steam:
    function:
      definition:f;
    bindings:
      f-in-0:
       destination: input-topic
      f-out-0:
       destination: output-topic
```

What i will need to do if I want to send a data from same function to two different topic?

Answer (score 1):

You can delimit destination values by comas

```
destination: output-topic,blah,foo
```

Comment: from within the Function how will i determine `a` should go to `topic1`, data `b` should go to to `Topic2`?

Comment: I thought you said "same function to two different topic", so each output will go to `topic1` and `topic2`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a function, use a `Consumer<?>` with a `StreamBridge` to determine which output(s) to send a message to.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources